# Can I still use Ionic project with SRC folder only

Tags: ionic-framework

Had a developer make a app for me. But he only sent me the src/ folder. Can I still use this to edit and build?

Comment: which version of ionic? Does it use cordova/capacitor? any custom plugins?

Comment: I have no idea what version. Is there any way of checking from the src folder? It does use Cordova.

Comment: If you have package.json file...which is supposed to be in the outer folder. You don't even have the dependencies ?

Comment: I now have package.json and src folder. If I give this to another developer would they be able to open the project up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some extra effort and guess work.  Some considerations:

- There is a `resources` directory which is typically a peer of `src`, which contains icons and splash screen assets used during the build process (if you had those icons).
- The root of the project (one level up from `src`) has a good deal of important items

  - `config.xml` - contains formal app name & version (for app stores), contains critical native build info for cordova plugins, can contain "whitelist" setups, contains desired ios/android platform versions, can contain special build adjustments, etc.
  - `package.json` - contains the list of NPM packages (and versions) needed to make the app build and run, and can contain other build steps used during setup.
  - various other files, depending on the app (e.g. push notification setup files, unit testing setup files, etc.)
- Besides the source files, it's also very helpful to know the version of the Cordova CLI and the Ionic CLI used to build the app.  Often times getting different versions of these can cause mixed results when building.

Comment: Is it possible to use the outer root folder of a similar project by the same developer (using same plugins etc) but replace the src folder with the src I have been provided?

Comment: Boy, I'd have to give that a strong *maybe*.  Totally depends on if that similar project has the same plugins/dependencies/versions/etc.

Comment: I now have the package.json and the src folder. Developer refuses to provide all remaining folders. Does this better my chances at all?

Comment: Better chances, yes.  But there is still some guess work.  As seen in my answer above, the package.json is only one of the details I mentioned.